# python solve Cubic equation without using sympy

Tags: python, numpy, math, sympy

Is it possible to solve Cubic equation without using sympy?

Example:

```
import sympy as sp
xp = 30
num = xp + 4.44
sp.var('x, a, b, c, d')
Sol3 = sp.solve(0.0509 * x ** 3 + 0.0192 * x ** 2 + 3.68 * x - num, x)
```

The result is:

```
[6.07118098358257, -3.2241955998463 - 10.0524891203436*I, -3.2241955998463 + 10.0524891203436*I]
```

But I want to find a way to do it with numpy or without 3 part lib at all

I tried with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
coeff = [0.0509, 0.0192, 3.68, --4.44]
print(np.roots(coeff))
```

But the result is :

```
[ 0.40668245+8.54994773j  0.40668245-8.54994773j -1.19057511+0.j]
```

Comment: You have a typo: `np.roots([0.0509, 0.0192, 3.68, -34.44])` gives the same result as with `sympy`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your numpy method you are making two slight mistakes with the final coefficient.

In the `SymPy` example your last coefficient is `- num`, this is, according to your code: `-num = - (xp + 4.44) = -(30 + 4.44) = -34.44`

In your `NumPy` example yout last coefficient is `--4.44`, which is `4.44` and does not equal `-34.33`.

If you edit the `NumPy` code you will get:

```py
import numpy as np
coeff = [0.0509, 0.0192, 3.68, -34.44]
print(np.roots(coeff))
[-3.2241956 +10.05248912j -3.2241956 -10.05248912j
  6.07118098 +0.j        ]
```

The answer are thus the same (note that `NumPy` uses `j` to indicate a complex number. `SymPy` used `I`)

Comment: tnx, but the result with numpy not spllited like that:
[6.07118098358257, -3.2241955998463 - 10.0524891203436*I, -3.2241955998463 + 10.0524891203436*I]

Comment: there is a way to split it or to show only the regular number without j ?

Comment: @rambler You can get the real part and imaginary part of each root (I don't know what the names of those functions are in numpy) and then print them in a way that makes more sense for your purposes.

Comment: Hi Rambler, yes you can do that. You can extract the real and imaginary parts of complex numbers with: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.imag.html and https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.real.html.

Comment: thank you!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the [cubic formula](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/)

[image]

this Youtube video from [mathologer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-KXStupwsc) could help understand it.

Based on that, the cubic function for ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0 can be written like this:

```
def cubic(a,b,c,d):
    n = -b**3/27/a**3 + b*c/6/a**2 - d/2/a
    s = (n**2 + (c/3/a - b**2/9/a**2)**3)**0.5
    r0 = (n-s)**(1/3)+(n+s)**(1/3) - b/3/a
    r1 = (n+s)**(1/3)+(n+s)**(1/3) - b/3/a
    r2 = (n-s)**(1/3)+(n-s)**(1/3) - b/3/a
    return (r0,r1,r2)
```

The simplified version of the formula only needs to get c and d as parameters (aka p and q) and can be implemented like this:

```
def cubic(p,q):
    n = -q/2
    s = (q*q/4+p**3/27)**0.5
    r0 = (n-s)**(1/3)+(n+s)**(1/3)
    r1 = (n+s)**(1/3)+(n+s)**(1/3)
    r2 = (n-s)**(1/3)+(n-s)**(1/3)
    return (r0,r1,r2)

print(cubic(-15,-126))
(5.999999999999999, 9.999999999999998, 2.0)
```

*I'll let you mix in complex number operations to properly get all 3 roots*

Comment: I think there are no quarantees that these square roots contain are non-negative.

Comment: @mathfux why would they need to be non-negative? The two cubic roots are conjugate, and the formula would give a (real) root anyway. That said, I don't think this answers OP's question.